# MVVM adding a Console to a window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am writing an application that connects to a server via `SSH` and runs a script that processes files. The backend stuff on the server works fine, but I would like a console window in my `WPF` application that I can monitor the process. I am doing my best to follow the `MVVM` pattern. I have achieved this before in a `WPF` application but I was using the code behind to be able to get a handle on a TextBox element that was in the View. I can't do it that way following `MVVM` since your not really supposed to have anything in your code-behind.

Here is my `StudyImporterView.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="DICOM_Importer.Views.StudyImporterView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DICOM_Importer.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Gold"
        Title="Importer" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource gridBackground}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="280" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Content="Study:" />
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Name="StudyImportViewStudyText" Content="{Binding ImporterTitle}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Content="Import Directory" />
            <Label Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyTitle}}" Content="{Binding ImporterPath}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ImportCommand}" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource buttonStyleImport}}" Content="Submit" />

        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ImportConsole" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the `StudyImporterViewModel.cs`

```
using DICOM_Importer.Commands;
using DICOM_Importer.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DICOM_Importer.ViewModels
{
    public class StudyImporterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private string importerTitle;
        private string importerPath;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the study information from the HomeView
        /// </summary>
        public String ImporterTitle
        {
            get { return importerTitle; }
            set
            {
                importerTitle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImporterTitle");
            }
        }

        public String ImporterPath
        {
            get { return importerPath; }
            set
            {
                importerPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImporterPath");
            }
        }

        ConsoleOutputStream outputter;

        public StudyImporterViewModel()
        {
            ImportCommand = new ActivateImport(this);
            outputter = new ConsoleOutputStream(ImportConsole);
        }

        public ICommand ImportCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void Import()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing Console");
        }

        #region Error Model
        public string Error
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Error Definition
        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get 
            {
                if (columnName == "ImporterTitle")
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ImporterPath))
                    {
                        Error = "There is no selected study to import";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Error = null;
                    }
                }
                return Error;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region PropertyChangedEventHandler
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion


    }
}
```

this is my class that creates the Output Stream for the Console
`ConsoleOutputStream.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DICOM_Importer.Commands
{
    class ConsoleOutputStream : TextWriter
    {
        TextBox textBox = null;


        public ConsoleOutputStream(TextBox ouput)
        {
            textBox = ouput;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                textBox.AppendText(value.ToString());
            }));
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose if there is not a good way to do this and follow `MVVM`, I'll just break `MVVM` and use the code behind.

Comment: What makes you feel using code behind breaks MVVM? How do you think are all of the controls are written?

Comment: It is my understanding that in true MVVM that if I am getting a Output stream from my SSH session to be displayed in the WPF application that all that logic should be contained in my ViewModel. There should be no logic in the View and the ViewModel should be complete detached to the View. I am new to MVVM, so I could be mistaken.

Comment: When you habe to calculate the size of a control then this logic has to be done by the view. The view is responsible for the whole presentation logic and not a layer without any logic.

Comment: do you have any suggestions to achieve this in a MVVM pattern?

Comment: Use/Build a control that can present the console

Comment: separation of concerns in MVVM pattern applies to its layers. There is nothing to separate in a console "control". unless of course you want to treat each line or character as a concept, then each will have its own view and viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM practice would suggest that nothing outside your View should have a reference to parts of your View - i.e. you should not be writing to your TextBox anywhere except inside your View. Nothing outside the View should know directly about the TextBox (or any other control).

Currently you seem to have a reference in your ViewModel to the TextBox (ImportConsole) and I'm not sure how that would even compile.

What you want to do is have the ConsoleOutputStream and the ViewModel only deal with strings (data), not TextBox controls.

You could data bind a string representing the entire contents of the TextBox but this probably wouldn't perform well (although nothing wrong with trying it - performance might not be an issue).

Alternatively, you could raise an event from your ViewModel and from your ConsoleOutputStream which signals a new row of text that has been received. The View can listen for this event (in the code-behind - yes that's perfectly fine) and append text to the TextBox.

The ConsoleOutputStream raises an event which is caught by the ViewModel. The event args contains the new string to be appended. The ViewModel raises the same event which is caught by the View, and the View appends the text to the TextBox.

What this means is, you can unit test your ViewModel and ConsoleOutputStream in isolation of your View - which is one of the main purposes of MVVM.

A further alternative is to use a ListBox which is data-bound to an ObservableCollection of strings which are appended to when you receive data. That would require no code-behind at all (although, again, that in and of itself need not be a strict goal when using MVVM).